# Points plotted by DateTimeTick Formatter in a bokeh scatter plot move in xaxis

Tags: python, python-2.7, bokeh

When using Bokeh plot I find the following issues:

1) The plot does not show the points immediately.

2) When I zoom out using mouse wheel 3 times the points become visible.

3) When I zoom out 7 times the points are shifted to the next/previous minute(In my case they are between 40m:54s and 41m originally after 7th zoom they go to 40:38 to 40:44)

I have tried setting
    g.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
to 0 with no luck

```
import pandas as pd
import bokeh
from bokeh.plotting import *
from bokeh.io import output_file,show,save
from bokeh.resources import CDN,INLINE
from bokeh.embed import file_html
from bokeh.models.ranges import *
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral6
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap
from bokeh.transform import dodge
from bokeh.core.properties import value
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.layouts import row,column
from bokeh.models import DatetimeTickFormatter


myPandas = pd.read_pickle("myPanda.pickle")
source=ColumnDataSource(data=myPandas)
yaxis="yaxis"
xaxis="xaxis"
def getTitle(graphDet):
    return graphDet

graphDet="Dummy"
g = figure(plot_width=450, plot_height=300, y_axis_label=yaxis, x_axis_label=xaxis, output_backend="webgl", title=getTitle(graphDet), x_axis_type="datetime")
x="time"
y="col1"
g.circle(myPandas[x],myPandas[y], size=5,legend=value(y))
g.xaxis[0].formatter=DatetimeTickFormatter(milliseconds = ['%3Nms']
                                        ,seconds = ['%Ss']
                                        )

g.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
g.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
g.legend.location = "top_right"
g.legend.orientation = "vertical"
show(g)
```

The pickle file for input can be found in 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4fe11kdu00nbcjp/myPanda.pickle?dl=0

My expectation is the plot must be visible right from the start.It must not jump across time.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug introduced wheh `webgl` is used. Removing it solves the problem but is this acceptable for you? (tested on bokeh v1.0.4)

```
import pandas as pd
import bokeh
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import *
from bokeh.io import output_file, show, save
from bokeh.resources import CDN, INLINE
from bokeh.embed import file_html
from bokeh.models.ranges import *
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral6
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap
from bokeh.transform import dodge
from bokeh.core.properties import value
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models import DatetimeTickFormatter
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

d_start = datetime(2016, 6, 1)
d_step = timedelta(milliseconds = 100)

t = [d_start + (i * d_step) for i in range(0, 100)]
myPandas = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['time', 'col1'], data = {'time': t, 'col1': np.arange(100)}, index = t)
source = ColumnDataSource(data = myPandas)

def getTitle(graphDet):
    return graphDet

graphDet = "Dummy"
g = figure(plot_width = 450, plot_height = 300, y_axis_label = "yaxis", x_axis_label = "xaxis", title = getTitle(graphDet), x_axis_type = "datetime")
x = "time"
y = "col1"
g.circle(myPandas[x], myPandas[y], size = 5, legend = value(y))
g.xaxis[0].formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(seconds = ['%Ss'], milliseconds = ['%3Nms'])

g.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
g.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
g.legend.location = "top_right"
g.legend.orientation = "vertical"
show(g)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this does solve my problem but the data I have posted is a very small portion of the total data.So loading that on a web browser without webgl will be very time consuming and also increases the chances of crash/unresponsive behaviour on the browser. Also I plot around 20 such plots.Is there any other way/package you would recommend to do the same? I am using bokeh version 0.13.0.

Comment: I just found that there is a issue open for this in github. https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/8687

Comment: I would recommend you http://datashader.org/ to preprocess the data before showing it in Bokeh